# Refresh admin page after woocommerce order received

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am little bit new to this. I want my admin woocommerce orders page to be loaded or be refreshed after someone placed an order. So, we can see if there is an order.

I use woocommerce hooks and java script.

This is what I tried:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'your_function', 99, 3 );

function your_function( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ){
    if( $new_status == "completed" ) {
        echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                window.location.replace(\"http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order");
            </script>
        ";
    }
}
```

but nothing is happening. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: The admin page on your computer is not the same as the order page on the customers computer, once the page is loaded it's loaded. For what you want to do you'd need to it constantly be pinging the site asking "Hey has there been a new order yet?", you can't use a page load to modify the contents of something that's already been sent out in a totally separate page load. It's like telling a printer to insert a piece of text and expecting all previous printed copies of that document to now contain the text

Comment: how can I ask constantly if is there new order?